# Error on large files with GridFS and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I seem to be getting an error when trying to upload large files into MongoDB..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoGridFSException' with message 'could not open file ' in /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/thundergrid.php:33 Stack trace: #0 /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/thundergrid.php(33): MongoGridFS->storeUpload('pic', Array) #1 /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/admin/index.php(7): Admin->upload() #2 {main} Next exception 'MongoGridFSException' with message 'error setting up file: ' in /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/thundergrid.php:33 Stack trace: #0 /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/thundergrid.php(0): MongoGridFS->storeUpload() #1 /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/admin/index.php(7): Admin->upload() #2 {main} thrown in /home/jclark/thundergrid.fusionstrike.com/thundergrid/thundergrid.php on line 33
```

Is there a reason I'm getting these or...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is over 2GB/4GB, then this is likely a limitation on how PHP is build on your platform. In most cases, LFS (large file system) is not enabled (and theoretically it's not officially supported by the PHP dev team either). It is also possible that you are using a 32-bit compile of PHP as well, in which case you need a 64-bit build.

Comment: Then it is very likely not a limitation (or a large file!). Please share your code as well in the question then.

Comment: The source is https://github.com/Bioshox/Thundergrid/blob/master/classes/admin.php, although at the time this question was asked it was https://github.com/Bioshox/Thundergrid/commit/eb376cb4bfbb91dde6f90746363f0832b94d8484#L3L32