# Php-MongoGridFS weeor in storeFile() function

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

i am trying to use MongoGridFS to deal with image files.
below is my code that i am trying..

```
$m = new MongoClient();
   // select a database
   $dbInput = "json";
   $db = $m->$dbInput;
    var_dump($mongo_fs= $db->getGridFS());//new MongoGridFS($db,"files_coll");
    //$file_id=$mongo_fs->put("Jellyfish.jpg");
    $id=1234;
    $mongo_fs->storeFile("act.php", array("_id" => $id));
    //var_dump($file = $mongo_fs->get($file_id));
    echo $gridFS->findOne(array("_id" => $id))->getBytes();
```

both files 'act.php' & 'Jellyfish.jpg' are available in a same directory as that of the source file.
I am getting an error-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoGridFSException' with message
>   'could not open file act.php' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDB\mongo_files.php:10 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDB\mongo_files.php(10):
>   MongoGridFS->storeFile('act.php', Array) #1 {main} Next exception
>   'MongoGridFSException' with message 'error setting up file: act.php'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDB\mongo_files.php:10 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDB\mongo_files.php(0): MongoGridFS->storeFile()
>   1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDB\mongo_files.php on line 10

i searched a lot over internet.
this question might be the same as of [Error on large files with GridFS and MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184796/error-on-large-files-with-gridfs-and-mongodb) but i am not trying to upload any large file and i am not using 'html form' to upload anything.
Any answer is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are your image files over 16MB? if not then save yourself some trouble and do not use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/). The link is there so you actually read what GridFS really is. Where your files are smaller than 16MB (BSON Document size limit), then simply store the binary data directly within a field of a document. MongoDB is happy to do this, and in fact that is all the GridFS "library functions" are actually doing, but just breaking up large content into "chunks" small enough to fit.

Comment: @BlakesSeven currently i am just trying with smaller files but in future there are pretty good chances of dealing with large files. and also GridFS provides direct functions to access & store files into the MongoDB thats why i was thinking to use it. Any further suggestions are welcomed. :)

Comment: My suggestion was there. The only "large files" I would typically deal with in a general website are "way under" 64MB (which is really big for an image) therefore it is much more efficient to store them directly in a single document. GridFS is highly overused, which is my point. Use it only for the applications where you really do need it. There is considerable overhead involved for smaller files.

Comment: your suggestion sounds good but it'll be appreciated if you share some example to do the same without using the GridFS as i am getting only GridFS to store files in MongoDB as a result if i google for the same.